# Transfer permanent residence to other country

Tags: blue-card, residency, czech-republic

I live in Czechia, and I'm getting married to a Slovak guy. We are considering moving to Hungary. I have blue card and only a few months till permanent residence in Czechia. My goal would be dual citizenship in EU country and my home country.

If I move to Hungary, do I have to save up 10 years again to get citizenship, or can I use the 5 years from Czechia too? Does the blue card help at all?

Regarding permanent residence, can it be transferred? With blue card can I transfer all 5 years in Czechia for permanent residence in Hungary, even if I had blue card in Czechia only 1 year?

Comment: I think you cannot https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/blue-card/essential-information_en

Comment: Note that the time you need to be resident in a country to be eligible for citizenship varies by country.  In Germany it is currently 8 years, and the government is planning to reduce that.

Answer (score 1):

> If I move to Hungary, do I have to save up 10 years again to get citizenship, or can I use the 5 years from Czechia too? Does the blue card help at all?

That's entirely up to Hungary. EU law doesn't mandate anything, it doesn't have to be 10 years, it doesn't even have to be possible at all. I am not sure whether the EU Blue Card helps anywhere but I don't think so. You may also want to consider Slovak citizenship (if it is available to you as the spouse of a Slovak citizen living abroad).

> Regarding permanent residence, can it be transferred? With blue card can I transfer all 5 years in Czechia for permanent residence in Hungary, even if I had blue card in Czechia only 1 year?

Not exactly but the EU Blue card does provide significant advantages regarding the EU long-term resident status. You will need to have resided at least two years (instead of five) in Hungary *under an EU blue card* to gain that status so you can kind of “transfer” three years. Any national permanent residence (distinct from the EU long-term resident status) can also have its own rules.

Note that this only works if you still qualify for an EU Blue card in Hungary. If you reside there based on your link with your EU citizen husband or on any other legal basis, other rules apply (but the EU citizen's family route can be advantageous and also offers a path to another kind of permanent residence status).

Another option is to wait to be a long-term resident before the move. In that scenario, you would at least retain the right to come back to the Czech republic until you become a long-term resident in Hungary.

Comment: I don't have time to remind myself of the details, but I recall that permanent residence under the free movement directive is more secure than long-term residence.  But I suppose it may be less portable (to other EU countries) if the marriage ends.  Am I right about either?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/blue-card/essential-information_en

> With an EU Blue Card, it will be easier for you to get long-term residence status, as the rules for calculating the period of time necessary are more generous (you can add together periods of time spent in different EU countries, instead of the whole five years being in just one EU country).

<s>So if you get a Blue Card in Hungary, you can immediately apply for permanent residence there.</s> What this doesn't say, is that you have to spend two years in Hungary to apply for EU long term residence, and can then use the time in Czechia to bring the total up to five years (see [the directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32009L0050)).  Also that this is "EU long term residence", not any national "permanent residence" status.  (Although the former may be more useful to you anyway.)

However, [this (non-official) site](https://visaguide.world/europe/hungary-visa/citizenship/) says that you need "eight years continuous residence in the territory of Hungary".  The bad news is that you would reset the clock, the good news is that (as far as I can see), time in Hungary on a Blue Card counts - you don't have to get permanent residency and *then* wait eight years.

Comment: The paragraph you're quoting is somewhat imprecise. It's true that it's easier and that you can “add together periods of time spent in different EU countries” but it doesn't actually say that you can apply immediately. In fact, you need at least two years in the country where you apply (and what you “add” are the other three years required to reach the total of five). Also note that this is strictly about the EU long-term resident status, any national “permanent resident” status would have its own rules.

Comment: @Relaxed: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Yes, of course, the directive itself, [Directive 2009/50/EC, article 16](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32009L0050). But really, your source doesn't support your interpretation, it simply *does not state* that you can apply immediately. That's the reason for the somewhat convoluted phrasing. If you could apply after 5 years anywhere in the EU, they would simply say so.