# EU long term residence permit and Blue card renewal

Tags: resident-permit, eu, poland

People can apply for EU long term residence permit after 5 years of staying legally in Poland. For me, it will be December 2025.

The [gov.pl](https://www.gov.pl/web/udsc-en/permit-for-residence-of-a-long-term-eu-resident) website has a remark about uninterrupted 5 years of stay:

> –    The whole residence under the EU Blue Card, whether issued in Poland or in another EU Member State (provided that the last 2 years before the application for the permit for residence of a long-term EU resident have been spent in Poland under the Blue Card);

So does this mean, that in order to apply for EU long term residence permit, I must have a valid Blue Card for 2 years?

The issue is that my current blue card will expire next year, so I'm in the process of applying for a new one. Given delays, it is expected to take around 7–8 months to get a new Blue Card in my area, so say I will receive mine around March 2024. Does it mean that I will be eligible to apply for EU long-term residence not December 2025, but March 2026?

Comment: What is your status now and what will be your status while waiting for the renewal?

Comment: The bit about the last two years actually refers to a special rule for people who lived in several EU countries under an EU Blue card, see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/26262/transfer-permanent-residence-to-other-country If that's not your case (you have resided in Poland for the last five years) then it's irrelevant and you can ignore it. You do need to make sure your whole stay in Poland was under some status that qualifies for permanent residence but not necessarily a Blue Card.

Comment: @Relaxed current status is Blue Card, my status while waiting for the renewal will be somewhat mixed. Blue Card expires in April, so if there are delays I will be some time just waiting for a new card with an expired current one.

My 5 years stay in Poland will be based either on working visa (first half a year in the country) and then on Blue Card (current one and the renewed one I'm going to apply for). Hope it will work as you described. Thank you.